# UIView center not changing

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a view that contains a sub view that has its center changed by a method parameter.

It's working fine in a normal view controller, but when I add it to a modal view controller's view, the change in center is being ignored. If a place a button in the modal view controller and call the method in the touch up event, it works fine. Obviously, the timing of the method call is critical. I've tried everything I can think of to debug this and I am out of ideas. What's going on under the hood? Where should I be doing the call?

BTW The view is being loaded from a xib.

Comment: You need to show the code in your method.

Comment: _subview.center = newCenter

Comment: Since part of your question is where to make the call, you need to show the whole method, and how and where you are calling it.

Comment: I added a timer as a workaround